# Select continuous time intervals in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with datetimes and i need to select continuous time intervals

My table:

| Id | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:01:00 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:02:00 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:04:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 10:03:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 10:04:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 10:06:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 10:07:00 |

Result i need:

| id | date_from | date_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:00 | 2021-01-01 10:02:00 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:04:00 | 2021-01-01 10:04:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 10:03:00 | 2021-01-01 10:04:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 10:06:00 | 2021-01-01 10:07:00 |

I tried like this, but can't do that right

```
select id, 
  min(date_from) over 
    (partition by id, date_to 
       order by id) 
    as date_from, 
    max(date_to) over 
      (partition by id, date_from 
      order by id) 
    as date_to
    from (
      select id, 
      MIN(time) over 
        (PARTITION by id, 
        diff2 between 0 and 60
        ORDER BY id, time) 
      as date_from, 
      max(MINUTE) over 
        (PARTITION by id, 
        diff between 0 and 60
        ORDER BY id, time) 
      as date_to 
        from (
           select *, 
           unix_timestamp(date_lead) - unix_timestamp(time) 
              as diff, 
           unix_timestamp(time) - unix_timestamp(date_lag) 
              as diff2 
                    from (
                        select id, time,
                            NVL(LEAD(time) over 
                                (PARTITION by id 
                                ORDER BY id, time), time) 
                            as date_lead,
                            NVL(LAG(time) over 
                                (PARTITION by id 
                                ORDER BY id, time), time) 
                            as date_lag
                        from my_table) 
                    )
                )
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle?  If so, please update the tags under your question with your actual database.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, MIN(time), max(time) from 
    (SELECT * interval '1 minutes' *-1* (DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER by time) ) + TO_TIMESTAMP(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as drank 
from event) t1                                      
GROUP by drank, id
order by id
```

Comment: Hi, please add some explanation of your code (even inline comments are helpful!)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your time stamps are precise (no seconds or fractions of a second), you can subtract an enumerated number of minutes from the `time` column.  This is constant for "adjacent" rows:

```
select id, min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, time - seqnum * interval '1 minute';
```

If you have seconds and fractional seconds, then you might want to adjust the logic using `date_trunc()`.  If this is an issue, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.